# Why am I getting Interceptor attempted to ‘Proceed’ for a method without a target error?

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

In my case I have main project and test project. I was getting proper results on the test project where I have only one Installer class and register everything in one place. In my main project I had several installers (one for service, one for interceptors, one for common libraries, one for data persistence). For the main project I was getting the error specified:

*This is a DynamicProxy2 error: the inter­cep­tor attempted to ‘Pro­ceed’ for a method without a target, for example, an interface method or an abstract method*

I was struggling to find out what was wrong. I plugged into my constructor that accepts interface of a data persistence layer and saw that it only receives a proxy object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why this was happening is specified here: http://kozmic.net/2009/03/20/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-viii-interface-proxy-without-target/

Krzysztof explains that you Castle can **resolve** even an **interface**, and Windsor will create a class **for you**. However if you want to use an interceptor and call a invocation.Proceed() method you need to specify what happens inside that method (for ex. using lambda expression)

**Solution:**
In my case solution was to put all installers into one, except of the interceptor installer. That one could stay alone, and eveything was fine.

Answer (score 2):

Also, see here: [Manually Loading the Factory Extension into the Ninject Kernel](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Manually-Loading-the-Factory-Extension-into-the-Ninject-Kernel)

Under some circumstances it may be necessary to manually load the extension. The solution in my case was to add the following code during kernel construction:

```
if (!kernel.HasModule("Ninject.Extensions.Factory.FuncModule"))
{
    kernel.Load(new FuncModule());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem by Update method so change it like this :

```js
 var myObj = _dbContext.Set<T>().Find(entity.Id);
 _dbContext.Entry(myObj).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```